# Object moved this document may be found here php

Tags: php, html-parser

I'm redirecting my web page to another url. It works fine on localhost but when i host it to my web server then it give me the message which says "Object Moved This document may be found here". I don't know what is the issue here is my code.

```
foreach($html->find('a[class=btn btn-warning btn-block]') as $element) 
      $redic=$element->href;
       header("Location: $redic");
```

please help me what should i do to avoid this error. Thank you

Comment: That message sounds like the result of a [300-range HTTP response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection).

Answer (score 0):

Your path must not be absolute!
pathname that starts from the root path and specifies all directories between the root path and the specified directory or file.